# Uploaded image does not display in the web page until I refresh the page Spring Mvc webapp

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, tomcat, reload, image-upload

I upload profile image through web form and upload it to the static resources directory. The issue is the renewed image is not displayed in the user profile page until I does not refresh my spring mvc project.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: i used spring mvc with bootstrap html.To store and retrive,i saved the complete local drive path of the project folder